# Serialize a PowerShell class with BinaryFormatter

Tags: powershell, class, serialization

I'm trying to store a huge tree-like data structure:

```
[Serializable()]    
class TreeNode {

}
$tree = New-Object TreeNode
$fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream 'storage.bin', ([System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($fs, $tree)
$fs.Close()
```

But PowerShell raises a `SerializationException`:

```
Exception calling "Serialize" with "2" argument(s): "Type 'System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal' in Assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable."
```

Otherwise, storing nested `System.Collections.*` works just fine.

The question is, how `System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal` class mentioned in the error message is related to the instances of `TreeNode` or to the class itself?

I know there're `[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize`, `ConvertTo-JSON` and others; they're magnitudes slower, not gonna use them.

Comment: `[TreeNode].DeclaredFields`

Comment: If the class has an explicit constructor `TreeNode() { }`, the culprit `__sessionState` private property is set to `System.Management.Automation.SessionStateInternal` and can be changed to `$null` with Reflection. But it looks like `Serialize()` doesn't care about actual field value and still raises the same exception.